# Google search with a fixed string and a user editable string

Tags: javascript, string, web, search, google-search

I'm looking for a code to insert on a website that enables making a Google search while having a stored string attached in that search. Example, I would Google search "pitbull" and the Google search would return results of "pitbull awesome pics" being "awesome pics" the string always included in the Google search.

Comment: My friend, You want to modify a google search ? or you are talking about a search in your web application ?

Comment: Hello friend. I was thinking about a website with a google search box.
Do you have any clues for it?

Comment: you want to create your own custom search engine ? or it is something like a search functionality with in a website to search the website content ?

Comment: I wanted a website with just a search bar where I could insert for example: "corgi" and in the code it would have a string attached to the search like "pretty pics" and when I did search it would return "corgi pretty pics"
I think this might be really simple for ppl with a code background but I'm a noob in this, I did just a bit of html and css lol, so sorry for the silly question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do with with straight HTML.  Google search accepts multiple query parameters (`q=`).  You can create a HTML form with a hidden parameter for "corgi" and a user editable parameter as well.  Here is an example:

```html
<form action=https://www.google.com/search>
  <input type=text name=q value=corgi>
  <input type=hidden name=q value='pretty pics'>
  <input type=submit value=Search>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply.It seems a way to do it.
What if in the value i wanted more info besides corgi, like a string. example: "corgi" or "collie"

Comment: I had the hidden and visible fields swapped.  I just updated it so you can type different dogs but it always includes "pretty pics"

Comment: Thank you in the first place for your help.
The thing that I want to do is to have a hidden sentence that includes severeal words to google.
Example: "crime" or "news" or "scandal"
When I try to use your example and use this sentece as a hidden string the system only included the first word "crime". 

<form action=https://www.google.com/search>
  <input type=hidden name=q value="crime" or "news" or "scandal" >
  <input type=text name=q value='insert name'>
  <input type=submit value=Search>
</form>

or 

value=""crime" or "news" or "scandal""  (with extra "")

But doesnt work :(

Comment: An attribute value that has quotation marks in it needs to be quoted with single quotes.  In other words: `value='"crime" or "news" or "scandal"'`

Comment: Thank you that worked :)
In case I would like to create 2 actions with the same submit in order to open 2 new webspages one with "crime" and another with "scandal". Do I create 2 actions or create 2 forms and have the same variable to the input?

Comment: Instead of using `<input type=hidden name=q value='pretty pics'>` you could use a drop down with the two choices:  `<select name=q><option value=crime>Crime</option><option value=scandal>Scandal</option></select>`

Comment: My intention was to do both searches but the results to appear in 2 new webpages while performing the search with just one submit.
Is that possible?

Comment: You'd have to do submits for that.

Comment: So I can't use the same submit for both searches.